# Cannot acces properties of resulting array of cursor.fetch();

Tags: meteor

I have a helper where I want to acces the properties of a different collection.

```
Template.notification.helpers({

    username: function () {

        game = Games.findOne({_id: this.gameId}, {fields: {players:1}});
        console.log(game) // output is correct
   }
})
```

If I log this, it wil produce the result I expected:

```
Object {players: Array[2], _id: "qF3skjX2755BYcr8p"}
```

However, if I in my helper function I try to use/reach this properties I get an undefined error.

```
 Template.notification.helpers({

    username: function () {

        game = Games.findOne({_id: this.gameId}, {fields: {players:1}});
        console.log(game._id) // error;
        console.log(game.players) // error
   }
})
```

Output:

```
Exception from Deps recompute function: TypeError: Cannot read property 'players' of undefined
```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1):

This happens because when Meteor initiall loads on your web browser, all the html and js is ready, but the data is not yet ready.

If you tried to check `console.log(game)` it may be `null`. It does this only when the page has loaded. If you load the template after all the data has downloaded you wouldn't see this issue.

When the data arrives the `username` helper would re-run with the new data.

In the meanwhile you just need to take care of this exception:

```
var game = Games.findOne({_id: this.gameId}, {fields: {players:1}});
if(!game) return null;
```